# Counting data with SQL

Tags: sql, count, having

I have a table like the first table below (sorry if it doesn't show up correctly, I'm new to StackOverflow and haven't quite gotten the hang of how to show tables in the question).  I've already received help do a count of IDs that are not duplicated (I don't mean a distinct count. A distinct count would return a result of 7 (a, b, c, d, e, f, g). I wanted it to return a count of 4 (a, c, d, f). These are the IDs that do not have multiple type codes).  Now I need to take it a step further to show the count of how many times within a type code has a there is an ID with only that single type code. For example, we want to see a result like the second table below.  There are 2 instances of IDs that have a single type code of 444 (c, f), there is one instance of an ID that has a single type code of 111 (a), and 222 (d).

For reference, the query that got me the count of IDs that have only one type code is

```
select count(*) from
 (select id from 
  mytable 
  group by id 
  having count(*) =1) t


ID|type code
a|111
b|222
b|333
c|444
d|222
e|111
e|333
e|555
f|444
g|333
g|444

Type Code|Count
111|1
222|1
444|2
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.

Comment: In your question, don't talk about what other help you have received and what other possibilities exist.  Make your question as simple to understand as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is what you're asking for?

```
SELECT  [type code],
        COUNT(*) [count]
FROM    mytable
WHERE   [ID] IN ( SELECT    [ID]
                  FROM      mytable
                  GROUP BY  [ID]
                  HAVING COUNT([type code]) = 1)
GROUP BY [type code]
```

Comment: That looks like a great guess.

Comment: Note that those square brackets for delimited identifiers are product specific. ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g. `"type code"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using a nested aggregation:

```
SELECT type_code, COUNT(*) 
FROM
 ( -- as this looks for a single row you can simply add the type code
   SELECT ID, MIN(type_code) as type_code
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY  ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY type_code
```